# WordPress, how to use dynamic urls for the same page?

Tags: wordpress, url

I don't know if it's possible, but I want to configure a WordPress site to render the same page for all URLs that match the format `https://example.com/things/<any_word>`, the URL must keep its value.

For example,

The following URLs must show the same content:

- https://example.com/things/pencil
- https://example.com/things/book
- https://example.com/things/tv

Your help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

**1) Register your custom post type and create defalut template (the best option)**

**2) Add some custom code to page template (single.php or page.php ...) where your call a specific template for a specific category:**

```
 <?php  
  if (get_the_category(get_the_id())=='your-category')     
{
     
get_template_part( 'TEMPLATE_FOLDER/content', 'something' ); // "content-something.php"   

}    ?>
```

**3) Create a template and choose it for needed pages** [image]

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/